# Telescope / Meteor Image URLs and Hosting

Tags: meteor, telescope

I'm trying to change the logo for my Telescope app. Where should I place the image file? I can't seem to figure out what the correct file path (URL) should be.

Also, I use Bluehost.com for my web hosting. How do I deploy what I'm making to a web host? Can I just upload the directory?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to place your logo under the `public/img` directory of your Telescope app.

Then inside the Settings panel, enter this value :

```
/img/codehunt_logo.png
```

Later when your app will be deployed to production, you will have to change this value to the following :

```
http://codehunt.com/img/codegunt_logo.png
```

Concerning the deployment, the recommended way is to use [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up).

Telescope author made a video specifically about deploying to Digital Ocean + Compose.io, but you can use any other combination of services. (eg. AWS + MongoLab, etc...).

You'll find more info inside [Telescope documentation](http://telescope.readme.io/v0.20/docs/deploying).

Comment: Under 'telescope-core/public/img/'?

Comment: No, never modify core packages, put it under your app root public folder (create it if non-existent).

Answer (score 0):

Well in Meteor app all your images should be in public folder, you don't need to specify the complete path name... Just the name of image does the job!

No idea about the deployment!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get: Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "http://localhost:3000/logo.png."